# TFS 2013 - Is it possible to add parent file to existing file

Tags: tfs, tfs-2013

I had two created file that have same content. One was deleted from TFS 2013.
Is it possible to add history from deleted or to make deleted file parent of one that exist in TFS 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they will remain independent with separate histories.